# Algebraic set - Radical Ideal - $Rad(Rad(I))=Rad(I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In my lecture notes we have the following:

$V \subseteq K^n$ is an algebraic set $\Leftrightarrow$ it is of the form $V(I)$, where $I=$radical Ideal of $K[x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n]$.

It stands that $$Rad(Rad(I))=Rad(I)$$

How can we show that $$Rad(Rad(I))=Rad(I)$$ ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a\in\operatorname{Rad}(\operatorname{Rad}(I))$. Then $a^m\in\operatorname{Rad}(I)$, for some $m$. Then $(a^m)^n\in I$ for some $n$.

Comment: And the inverse inclusion is obvious, and general.

Comment: @RobertGreen Yes, of course.

Comment: I understand! Thanks! 

$$$$ 

Do you have also an idea for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127955/v-1-vx-y-and-v-2-vxy-are-algebraic-sets ? 
@egreg